# How to prevent VS Code from creating a directory named "~" (under Linux)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently trying to make VS Code a friend of mine, and so far, it does not look too bad.

However, under Linux, when I open a folder (via `Open Folder` menu item), it creates a new directory in that folder. This wouldn't be a problem if that new directory wouldn't be named `~`, which is the absolutely dumbest possible choice under Linux.

I had realized that this directory seems to be just for caching and speedup and wanted to delete it. So I went into my terminal, cd'ed into the folder I had previously opened, and was about to execute `rm -r ~`. One tenth of a second before my fingers hit `Enter`, I realized what I was doing and somehow managed to make my fingers take a deviation.

But I'd like to prevent such accidents once and forever, so I'd like to know how to keep VS Code from creating that directory, even if it would cost performance. Please bear with me if this question is silly or already has been asked, but googling for a search term which includes `~` as an important separate token does not seem to work very well ...

Comment: `~` is a perfectly fine name for a directory under Linux -- it's just that it's a bit harder to type if you need to `cd` in there or `ls` the contents or something.  I don't know whether VSCode has a Preferences dialog where you can set the cache folder name, but it might be easy enough just to remember to put quotes around `'~'` whenever you have to type it.  (ETA: I think you can actually do it just by saying `./~` instead of `~`.)

Comment: *~ is a perfectly fine name for a directory under Linux* But isn't it quite dangerous? What a mess if somebody forgets to put the quotes around it ... I've never seen another Linux application which creates a directory of this name (not being a Linux expert, though). And yep, I already had solved the 'problem' by prepending `./`. But I am not sure that it won't happen again, so I'd like to avoid accidents in the future ...

Comment: You're right that it has the potential to be dangerous, and for that reason, VS Code should be ashamed.  But if you need to use VSCode, and it doesn't have a cache directory preference option, you don't have a lot of choices.  I think there are some arguments for `rm` that allow you to avoid some of the more common oopses.  As for preventing the creation of `~`, the only thing I can think is to make a non-writable file, link or directory -- maybe VSCode will complain and ask you to enter an alternate name.  But having a file or link named `~` in your home directory isn't great either.

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1. I was hoping that VS Code provides an option (which I just have missed) to change the cache folder's name. So I guess I'll have to learn to live with it. I was somehow baffled because that was the first folder where VS Code behaved like that; in other folders (which basically contain the same kinds of files) it didn't create a cache folder. I'll try to investigate this during the next days.